# Objective-C локализация приложения

Tags: локализация, objective-c, ios

Доброе время суток, перед мною была поставлена задача локализации приложения - я подумал что тут нет ничего сложного (в зависимости от локализации iOS) перевести текст и вытягивать его по ключам. Но к сожалению задача не много другая, нужно что бы пользователь выбирал язык приложения из настроек приложения (извините за тавтологию). Собственно вопрос таков, как реализовать такую возможность, как потом определить язык в системе, где хранить, как это вообще реализуется? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Посмотрите вот [этот похожий топик](http://hashcode.ru/questions/243756/objective-c-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: я всегда когда возникает подобный вопрос (а возникает он почти у каждого заказчика, тяжелое наследие винды) ссылаюсь на то что этот путь не удовлетворяет правилам эппл и в ее системах нет понятия выбора локализации - в айоси подцепляется та локализация что выбрана, а в настольных системах есть порядок языков и берется тот что с более высоким приоритетом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en_EN", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
- (void)applyCustomLocalizationLanguage:(NSString *) localeCode {
     if (localeCode) {
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[localeCode] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
     } else {
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
     }
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

но этот **вариант не должен работать**, пока приложение не будет **перезапущено**. Еще один вариант - **через отдельный локализованный bundle**, вот тут есть пример такого проекта:
https://github.com/amjaliks/ObjCAdditions/tree/master/Source/Classes

Answer (score 1):

Подобный функционал возможно реализовать следующим образом: прописывать значения всех текстовых полей, лэйблов и т.д. в методах ViewDidLoad ваших вьюКонтроллеров. В них делать проверку какую пометку сделал пользователь о нужном языке (например при первом входе в программу, или на странице настроек). Эту пометку удобно сохранить в NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults. Т.е. метка о языке ставится подобным образом:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"RUS" forKey:@"preferLang"];
```

В ViewDidLoad:

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"preferLang"] isEqualToString:@"RUS"]) {
        _myTextField.text = @"текст на русском";
}
else {
        _myTextField.text = @"text in Eng";
}
```

Подобным образом язык будет меняться не выходя из приложения, только если выбор языка будет сделан на первом экране приложения. Если нужно сделать выбор языка так же где то дальше в приложении (в настройках например), и чтоб язык менялся на лету, то методы присваивания названий кнопкам, лэблам и т.д. нужно перенести в метод `ViewDidAppear`